# Selenium access to html webpage times out

Tags: c#, html, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to access a webpage using `Selenium` for `C#` and I am struggling to make some elements accessible. Some elements seem to be readily available whilst other do not.

An excerpt of the structure of the page is as follows:

```
<header class="l-quotepage__header">
<div class="c-faceplate c-faceplate--bond is-positive /*debug*/"
    data-faceplate=""
    data-faceplate-symbol="1rPFR0010870956"
    data-ist="1rPFR0010870956"
    data-ist-init="{&#34;symbol&#34;:&#34;1rPFR0010870956&#34;,&#34;high&#34;:0,&#34;low&#34;:0,&#34;previousClose&#34;:114.45,&#34;totalVolume&#34;:0,&#34;tradeDate&#34;:&#34;2024-03-27 09:34:21&#34;,&#34;variation&#34;:0,&#34;last&#34;:114.45,&#34;exchangeCode&#34;:&#34;PAR&#34;,&#34;category&#34;:&#34;BND&#34;,&#34;decimals&#34;:2}"
    data-ist-variation-indicator="">
  <input class="c-faceplate__accordion-toggle"
         id="faceplate-1492129610"
         type="checkbox"/>
  <div class="c-faceplate__body">
     <div class="c-faceplate__company">[...]</div>
     <div class="c-faceplate__data" data-faceplate-target="">
        <ul class="c-list-info__list c-list-info__list--split-half">
           <li class="c-list-info__item">
              <p class="c-list-info__heading u-color-neutral">open</p>
              <p class="c-list-info__value u-color-big-stone">
                 <span class="c-instrument c-instrument--open" data-ist-open="">0.00</span>
              </p>
           </li>
           <li class="c-list-info__item">
              <p class="c-list-info__heading u-color-neutral">previous close</p>
              <p class="c-list-info__value u-color-big-stone">
                 <span class="c-instrument c-instrument--previousclose"
                       data-ist-previousclose="">114.45</span>
              </p>
           </li>
           <li class="c-list-info__item">
              <p class="c-list-info__heading u-color-neutral">high</p>
              <p class="c-list-info__value u-color-big-stone">
                 <span class="c-instrument c-instrument--high" data-ist-high="">0.00</span>
              </p>
           </li>
           <li class="c-list-info__item">
              <p class="c-list-info__heading u-color-neutral">low</p>
              <p class="c-list-info__value u-color-big-stone">
                 <span class="c-instrument c-instrument--low" data-ist-low="">0.00</span>
              </p>
           </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="c-list-info__list c-list-info__list--split-half">
           <li class="c-list-info__item">
              <p class="c-list-info__heading u-color-neutral">volume</p>
              <p class="c-list-info__value u-color-big-stone">
                 <span class="c-instrument c-instrument--totalvolume" data-ist-totalvolume="">0</span>
              </p>
           </li>
           <li class="c-list-info__item">
              <p class="c-list-info__heading u-color-neutral">last trading time</p>
              <p class="c-list-info__value u-color-big-stone">
                 <span class="c-instrument c-instrument--tradedate" data-ist-tradedate="">27.03.24 / 09:34:21</span>
              </p>
           </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="c-list-info__list c-list-info__list--split-half@sm-max c-list-info__list--nowrap@md-min">
           <li class="c-list-info__item c-list-info__item--has-picto c-list-info__item--fixed-width">
              <p class="c-list-info__heading u-color-neutral">low threshold</p>
              <p class="c-list-info__value u-color-big-stone">114.94</p>
           </li>
           <li class="c-list-info__item c-list-info__item--has-picto c-list-info__item--fixed-width">
              <p class="c-list-info__heading u-color-neutral">high threshold</p>
              <p class="c-list-info__value u-color-big-stone">116.94</p>
           </li>
        </ul>
     </div>
  </div>
  <label class="c-faceplate__accordion-button" for="faceplate-1492129610"/>
 </div>    
</header>
```

Whilst I can access anything located within

```
<div class="c-faceplate__company">[...]</div>
```

I cannot access any of the data located within

```
<div class="c-faceplate__data" data-faceplate-target="">
```

I can locate the parent `IWebElement element` (here in `C#`) defined for the `XPath` //*div[@class="c-faceplate__data"] but, even after creating a `WebBrowserWait wait` to wait for it to be in `element.Displayed` or `element.Enabled` mode, makes it time out unsuccessfully (for long time spans such as up to 60s).

The data under this section are displayed on the UI side by toggling the button

```
<input class="c-faceplate__accordion-toggle"
     id="faceplate-1492129610"
     type="checkbox"/>
```

that comes with its label

```
<label class="c-faceplate__accordion-button" for="faceplate-1492129610"/>
```

although, on a full screen, the data under

```
<div class="c-faceplate__data" data-faceplate-target="">
```

are visible by default, only when one uses a reduced-sized screen does it disapppear and can only be made visible again by pressing the button. Other than this, the cross reference between the "input" 'id' and the "label" 'for', here "faceplate-1492129610", is random. The "faceplate-#" changes at each page call or refresh.

I am wondering to what extent does this button control the access to the div section too, how can I see if it is the case and how I can manage the `Selenium` browser to by-pass this hurdle.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the C# automation code? Otherwise it will be difficult to recommend a fix. We might suggest something you've already tried.